# Bigquery table sampling on partitioned data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to understand about bigquery table sampling mechanism.

From the official website https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling, what I understood is that the data is stored in number of blocks and sampling scans at least a whole block while.

How do I know how many blocks are there in a table? And how does sampling works in partitioned table? Is sampling always applied first before where clause?

If I have a date partitioned table, and I need some sample of a particular date partition then how can i achieve it with minimal cost? Can I use sampling in this case?

Comment: "BigQuery splits tables or table partitions into blocks if they are larger than about 1 GB"; I would therfore assume a block has a maximum of 1 GB of size. 
First optimize the query by selecting only the needed columns and partitions. If the query is much over 1GB, consider the sampling. If you run the quey several times, do not use sampling, because caching is disabled. If the size is above 10Gb, consider [search index](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-index).

Answer (score 1):

The TABLESAMPLE clause works by randomly selecting a percentage of data blocks from the table and reading all of the rows in the selected blocks. The sampling granularity is limited by the number of data blocks. Typically, BigQuery splits tables or table partitions into blocks if they are larger than about 1 GB.  Therefore as mentioned by @samuel assume a block has a maximum of 1 GB of size. First optimize the query by selecting only the needed columns and partitions. If the query is much over 1GB, consider the sampling. If you run the quey several times, do not use sampling, because caching is disabled. If the size is above 10Gb, consider [search index](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-index).